# Do you get another 3 months on each visit to New Zealand?

Tags: visas, new-zealand

Asking a very similar question to this [Do you get another 6 months on each visit to New Zealand?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/91572/do-you-get-another-6-months-on-each-visit-to-new-zealand) however I am a US rather than a UK citizen so my visa waiver visa is a shorter duration than that for a UK citizen, which leads me to question what other terms of the visa might also be different.

Specifically, I am in New Zealand on a 3 month visa waiver visa, and have been asked to return to the US for a brief (5 day) stay, after which I would return immediately to New Zealand.

I am a bit concerned by the line from this page of guidelines https://www.immigration.govt.nz/new-zealand-visas/apply-for-a-visa/tools-and-information/general-information/variation-of-conditions-temporary-visas/varying-a-visitor-visa which reads, "Your visitor visa expires when you leave New Zealand."

As I am going to leave my wife in place in NZ with the bulk of my luggage, and because there is a chance I can whine and complain my way out of this trip to the US, references to official NZ government regulation or documentation would be greatly appreciated.  I have not been able to find such clarity myself.

Answer (score 1):

The Immigration NZ web site is clear, as you have discovered: your visa expires when you leave New Zealand.

However, you can return to New Zealand with a visa waiver provided you do not stay more than six months in a twelve month period ([Source](https://www.immigration.govt.nz/new-zealand-visas/options/visit/explore-visitor-visa-options) Enter your details and select Visa Waiver Visitor)

After 1st October 2019 the eTA scheme comes into play. Details on the same link as above. You can return to New Zealand within two years and get a second visa.

Comment: Will I be automatically granted a new visa waiver visitor visa, or will I instead need to apply for a visa modification for multiple entry conditions?  The link above suggests the latter, but I do not have enough time remaining for such a request to be approved.